# How to show current user's tag_id on a page called map while using ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to show the current user's tag_id and the datetime of the detection on a new page(index.html.erb) that is in a folder called map in the views folder.
I have tables called detections, lendings, users, and rfid_tag. these are the relationships.

User:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lendings
  has_many :rfid_tags, :through => :lendings
end
```

RfidTag (has a tag_id):

```
class RfidTag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :detections
  has_many :sensors, :through => :lendings
  has_many :users, :through => :lendings
end
```

Lending:

```
class Lending < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :rfid_tag
  belongs_to :user
end
```

detection (has the datetime):

```
class Detection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :sensor
  belongs_to :rfid_tag
end
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should get tag_id's of user's

```
  @user.rfid_tags.map(&:tag_id)
```

Or

```
@user.rfid_tags.pluck(:tag_id)
```

Comment: At least use `pluck(:tag_id)` instead.

Comment: Ok I will add this